# Perl Inserting at incremented points in a sequence

Tags: perl, loops, increment

I have a problem I am hoping someone could help with.

Using the following...

```
 my @sequence = (1..9);
 my $newSequence = join " - ", @sequence;
```

...I can print a hyphen seperated sequence of numbers `1 - 2 - 3 - 4 - 5 - 6 - 7 - 8 - 9`

The thing I am having problem with, and do not quite know the best logical way to solve, is a loop to increment the position of a variable string in the number sequence on each iteration (to produce the kind of output shown below).

```
my $varString = "DOG"
```

**The output I am looking to achieve:**

```
DOG - 2 - 3 - 4 - 5 - 6 - 7 - 8 - 9
1 - DOG - 3 - 4 - 5 - 6 - 7 - 8 - 9
1 - 2 - DOG - 4 - 5 - 6 - 7 - 8 - 9
1 - 2 - 3 - DOG - 5 - 6 - 7 - 8 - 9
1 - 2 - 3 - 4 - DOG - 6 - 7 - 8 - 9
1 - 2 - 3 - 4 - 5 - DOG - 7 - 8 - 9
1 - 2 - 3 - 4 - 5 - 6 - DOG - 8 - 9
1 - 2 - 3 - 4 - 5 - 6 - 7 - DOG - 9
1 - 2 - 3 - 4 - 5 - 6 - 7 - 8 - DOG
```

What would be the best way to go about doing this?
Your help with this would be much appreciated, many thanks

Comment: Insert at 0+0, then at 10+1, then at 20+2... in other words, you'll have two counters, one that is incremented in tens, the other in ones.  Or even one counter that increments by one each time, and insert at `$c*10+$c`, for example.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Am I missing something? Surely this is all that is required.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @sequence = 1 .. 9;

for my $i (0 .. $#sequence) {
  my @newseq = @sequence;
  $newseq[$i] = 'DOG';
  print join(' - ', @newseq), "\n";
}
```

**output**

```
DOG - 2 - 3 - 4 - 5 - 6 - 7 - 8 - 9
1 - DOG - 3 - 4 - 5 - 6 - 7 - 8 - 9
1 - 2 - DOG - 4 - 5 - 6 - 7 - 8 - 9
1 - 2 - 3 - DOG - 5 - 6 - 7 - 8 - 9
1 - 2 - 3 - 4 - DOG - 6 - 7 - 8 - 9
1 - 2 - 3 - 4 - 5 - DOG - 7 - 8 - 9
1 - 2 - 3 - 4 - 5 - 6 - DOG - 8 - 9
1 - 2 - 3 - 4 - 5 - 6 - 7 - DOG - 9
1 - 2 - 3 - 4 - 5 - 6 - 7 - 8 - DOG
```

---

**Update**

Here's an alternative for people who are preoccupied about increasing the idle time time of their CPU. I offer it because it is clearer as well as faster than either solution presented so far. The output is identical.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @sequence = 1 .. 9;

for my $i (0 .. $#sequence) {
  local $sequence[$i] = 'DOG';
  my $s = join(' - ', @sequence);
}
```

Comment: You are copying a lot of arrays for no reason there.

Comment: @gbtimmon I challenge you to do better. The above code does roughly *O(n²)* `SV` copies (the array copy), and `O(n²)` `SV*` copies (`@newseq` elements as arguments for `join` on the stack), plus some irrelevant linear factors. I can't access chorobas solution because I don't know how slicing is implemented, but if the ranges in the slice produce `SV`s, then we are definitively in the same complexity.

Comment: @gbtimmon: The way it works is *code*, (*run*, *optimize* if necessary)*. Not *optimize*, *code*, *run*

Comment: @Borodin \*Rolls eyes\* That make sense for developing large processes and programs when complexity is high and you are trying to keep the development complexity to a minimum. Writing simple functions like this that unoptimized is just lazy. An equally easy (but optimized) solution is on this page already and easy to find. If it does not take very much extra brain power to start optimized, why not do it?

Comment: @gbtimmon: I am sorry about your eye problem, but I completely disagree. Optimizing *everything* will take substantially more time than it saves unless the data you are dealing with is enormous. Laziness is famously a virtue when it comes to programming, and high-level languages themselves are a product of that laziness. You shouldn't even consider using Perl if you look for anything other than the most clear solution.

Comment: Again laziness is a virtue in the right context. You should know -- just because someone else said something in a clever way does not make it universally true so stop quoting quipy sayings at me. You are right optimizing everything will take substantially more time, but coding without understanding the implications of what you are doing is a good way to write bad code.  And the difference between what choroba suggested and what you suggested is someone taking the time to think about what is actually being done, that is all.

Comment: @gbtimmon: Yours is a very old-fashioned way of working. I'm afraid you couldn't be more wrong, but I am sure you aren't going to be persuaded otherwise so I shall say no more.

Comment: Im sorry you feel insulted, but there is nothing 'old fashioned' about what I suggest. I'm just going by the basics I learned in my (rather recent) software design classes, and 5 years experience in the field.

Answer (score 3):

A solution using array slices:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature qw(say);

my $size = 9;
my @sequence = 1 .. $size;
for my $pos (0 .. $size - 1) {
    say join ' - ', @sequence[ 0 .. $pos - 1 ],
                    'DOG',
                    @sequence[ $pos + 1 .. $size - 1 ];
}
```